# Rails ActiveRecord Model Linked List

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, linked-list

after intensive googling I will now state out a problem which seems to not occur often, but still is very basic. Linked Lists in Active Record. As far as I am now, we need two associations in the model:

```
class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent
  belongs_to :next, :class_name => 'Child', :foreign_key => 'next_id'
  belongs_to :previous, :class_name => 'Child', :foreign_key => 'previous_id'
end
```

So now we can get all children of a parent:

```
children = Child.where("parent_id = ?", parent_id)
```

And now to the question: I want of course to get all children from the database with one query, but I also want to go through the children in the linked order, which means first one will be the child with the previous attribute of nil, the next child will be the one which is connected by the firsts next attribute, and so on until the next attribute is nil.
Is it possible to do it like this, or do I need to query the first child, and then go from child to child without "precaching"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [resort](https://github.com/codegram/resort) and [ranked-model](https://github.com/mixonic/ranked-model) gems are other alternatives.
The first one uses an approach similar to linked lists. The second one uses a position attribute.

Comment: Finally we ended up using ranked-model

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use the Rails [acts_as_list](https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list) gem. It stores the position of the item in the list, and even scopes to parent objects for lists and `belongs_to`. it would solve this problem as well by allowing you to query all the elements and then sort them correctly.

Comment: The thought crossed my mind as well, but acts_as_list doesn't give you a linked-list's major benefit - cheap insertion and removal from arbitrary locations.

Comment: nice to know the gem acts_as_list (because until now, i had this implementation done by myself) but exactly this is what i want to get away from.... if deleting an object, i just want to change the attributes of the previous and the next model, and not go through hundreds of rows changing the position attribute

Comment: You can override the `destroy` method and make it so it updates it's neighbours' attributes.

Comment: @Draiken Well the question still is, if one can fetch all the childs from one parent, and then iterate through them the linked list way...

Comment: acts_as_list has some gotchas that are not mentioned in the README: http://rhnh.net/2010/06/30/acts-as-list-will-break-in-production